# Work with append

Tags: python, list, append

I have a number (`nsteps`) of groups of results (`data`). Each `data` has four subgroups of results (`len(nodeSets)`), one for each `nodelabel`.

I'd like to join in the same row the subgroups of results for each `nodelabel`. My code is like:

```
    for i in range(0,len(odb.rootAssembly.instances[myInstanceName].nodeSets['LOAD'].nodes)):
        for stepi in range(0, nsteps):
            stepName = odb.steps.values()[stepi].name 
            nodelabel = odb.rootAssembly.instances[myInstanceName].nodeSets['LOAD'].nodes[i].label
            hR='Node ' + myInstanceName + '.' +str(nodelabel)
            dCF3.append([odb.steps[stepName].historyRegions[hR].historyOutputs['CF3'].data])
```

My problem is that I get:

```
dCF3[0]=[[data in step1 for nodelabel 1]]
dCF3[1]=[[data in step2 for nodelabel 1]]
...
dCF3[n]=[[data in step1 for nodelabel 4]]
dCF3[n+1]=[[data in step2 for nodelabel 4]]
```

and I want:

```
dCF3[0]=[data in each stepi for nodelabel 1] #only one list
....
dCF3[3]=[data in each stepi for nodelabel 4] #only one list
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The question would be clearer if your code example actually made sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
for nodelabel in nodes:
    dCF3.append([data.stepi.nodelabel for stepi in range(0, nsteps)])
```

It would have been easier with some actual data to test the code with.

Comment: Added some code. I can add Data but it is too large